# Overwrite wp_enqueue_script under certain condition

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I have an enqueued script called `custom_js` that loads the file `js/custom.js`. I want the file to change when a certain condition is true, but it does not seem to work. Here is my code:

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'my_custom_js', 11);

function my_custom_js()
{
   wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/custom.js' );

   if ( some condition )
   {
       wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/custom-2.js');
   }
}
```

Enqueuing another script seems unnecessary to me; what is the best way to manipulate a script that has been enqueued? Also, it is not very clear to me - do I have to `register` custom enqueued scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `wp_enqueue_script()` in your code should be `wp_register_script()`. The enqueue function does the job while the register function is getting ready to do the job.

It is always better to rather create a new js file to keep things organised. As to calling them, you can do the following

```
wp_register_script( 'abc', 'path_to' );
wp_register_script( 'xyz', 'path_to' );

if ( 'condition_a' ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'abc' );
} else {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'xyz' );
}
```

As to whether or not to use the `_register_` function, you can use it if you want to. When enqueueing scripts conditionaly, like above, you can use the register function to get the scripts ready for loading if they are called upon by the condition, **BUT**, it is not necesarry

### EDIT

You can also use `wp_localize_script()` to pass PHP variables according to a certain condition to a js script, and then in your js script you can alter your script according to the value of the PHP condition

Comment: Isn't there a way to make it simpler? Ideally a single `if` statement

Comment: How do you mean a single if statement. There is the way in my first code block, and then the other way of using `wp_localize_script()` to pass the PHP to JS and then doing something in JS according to the PHP passed. I cannot see how one can make this simpler

Comment: Sorry, I mean without an `else` statement

Comment: I think that you do not understand PHP. If you need to do something else instead of what you are currently doing, you will need an if/else statement. (*or ternary as TheDeadMedic, which is exactly the same thing*). Even if you pass a PHP variable to JS script via `wp_localize_script()`, you will need some sort of if/else statement in PHP and in JS.

Comment: Not necessarily, I think the following: `$var = "script1"; if(something) { $var = "script2"; }` is more elegant and minimal.

Comment: It remains the same concept, and is personal choice. It is like 6 eggs or a half a dozen of eggs. At the end, it does exactly the same job. Anyways, it is up to you, I did my best to answer this

Answer (score 2):

Just alter the script URL depending on the condition:

```
function my_custom_js() {
    $file = some_condition() ? 'custom' : 'custom-2';

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom_js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/$file.js"
        /* array( 'jquery' ) */ /* dependencies, if any */
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_js' );
```

You shouldn't be using `wp_print_scripts` - if you need the script to print after another, use the dependencies argument to specify which scripts yours requires.

Comment: I did not even realize the `wp_print_scripts` hook, good spot. A ternary statement is still just an if statement, which the OP does not want. I'm at a point where I do not know what the OP needs exactly, because I cannot see how you are going to get this done without somekind of if/else staement ;-)

Comment: I think OP wasn't actually opposed to the concept of `if` statements, just wanted something more concise.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I do have dependencies assigned but removed them to keep the question simple - why is `wp_enqueue_scripts` better than `wp_print_scripts`?

Comment: The clue is in the name - _enqueue_ - `wp_print_scripts` is specifically for _at point of printing scripts_.

Comment: All right, thanks for the points. I might just use @PieterGoosen solution as I'm afraid using the same name for `enqueue_script` might cause conflicts with plugins, especially caching ones.